# Localhost express mongodb server, fetch request to localhost returns 400 status

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

```
const data = {
    email: "paul@Smith.com",
    password: "PaulPass"
}
const body = JSON.stringify(data)
const paramsPost = {
   method: "POST",
    body: body
}
async function fetchContent() {
    console.log(paramsPost)
  let res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", paramsPost);
  console.log(res)
```

When I make  run this function and fetch the response the console log prints out:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}
```

Could you tell me why it is doing this? What did I do wrong? When I make the request on postman the request gives me a status 200 and returns a JWT.

Thank you,

Snow

Comment: Have you enabled CORS in your browser?

Comment: I did this in the server side ... 

//Middlewears
app.use(express.json());

  app.use(cors());

does that enable it in the browser?

Comment: Changing the params to this: 

const paramsPost = {
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
   method: "POST",
    body: body
}

gives status 200! but the token is not in the params ...

Answer (score 1):

Changing the params to this:

```
const paramsPost = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: body
  }
```

gives status 200!

I guess this is the answer but its very unsatisfying as what I wanted was the res.header

It's still undefined.